# Using ps and awk to get pid, then killing it

Tags: bash, awk, alias, kill, ps

I have written a very short script that gets pid of $1 then kills the process. I have a few questions / requests for improvement. (OSX)

```
#!/bin/bash

getpid=$(ps aux -O start | grep -i "$1" | grep -v grep | grep -v $0 | awk '{ if (NR==1) {print $2}}')

kill $getpid
```

For example:

```
$ ~/killpro.sh java
```

Which kills the most recent instance of java.

Or:

```
$ ~/killpro.sh chrome
```

To kill Google Chrome, obviously.

First, is there any practical way to get this strung together into a single line, using read -p perhaps, so that it can in turn be aliased and become something like:

```
$ killpro
$ Enter name: chrome
$
```

Not that it's significantly easier, in fact it's slightly more work, but it bypasses the need to type a path and shell extension which is desirable.

Second, is there anything fundamentally wrong with my initial approach / am I missing something obvious that negates the need for any this?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks in advance, I'm (as you can tell) new to this.

Comment: Doesn't OS X have a `killall` or `pidof` command?

Comment: @melpomene: It has `killall`, but it can't kill only the latest process. No `pidof`, but it's easy enough to implement.

Comment: shell scripts can have anyname. the `.sh` extension is just to indicate what is in there. You could use `file killpro` and it would report something like `shell script`. So just name your script `killpro`. THEN you need a local dir, commonly `~/usr/local/bin` to store your script AND edit your `.bashrc` or elsewhere to indicate `export PATH="~/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`. Then no pesky function or alias definitions required. Just type `killpro` and it will run. Good luck.

Comment: Please only post one question per question.

Answer (score 4):

My advice is to use pkill instead. From the manual page:

```
NAME
 pgrep, pkill -- find or signal processes by name
```

Answer (score 1):

Most scripts with `grep | awk` are a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and should be refactored to use just Awk.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Maybe add a case for $# > 1 and quit with an error message
# Or maybe loop over arguments if there is more than one
case $# in 0) read -p "Process name? " proc;; *) proc=$1;; esac

# Maybe your ps aux doesn't have the command in $11 -- adapt
kill $(ps aux -O start |
    awk -v name="$proc" 'NR>1 && tolower($11) ~ tolower(name) {print $2}')
```

Your comments indicate you seek to kill the "latest" process (by which metric?) but your code, and this code, attempts to kill all the instances.  If you want the most recently started process, the PID is not a good indicator; you should look at process start times etc.  The output of `ps` is heavily system-dependent so you should probably post a separate question with more details about your OS if you need help figuring that out.

This particular problem regularly gets beaten to death several times a month here, so you should probably look at other implementations for inspiration.  My recommendation would be "don't do that" but since you already did, I suppose it makes sense to point out the flaws and attempt to solidify the code.  But if you don't have a compelling reason why you cannot install `pkill`, you should probably just use that (and if you do, using a properly debugged and tested script is way better than writing your own from scratch).

Comment: I removed my comment because it depends on how the OP wants to determine the *latest* process. But probably `-newest` and `-oldest` flags of `pgrep/pkill` will work for the OP. At the end I can imagine of use cases were `awk` still comes handy, but first one might try to achieve the task with `pgrep/pkill`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Added a pointer to `pkill` to the final paragraph of musings.

Comment: Why is the PID not a good indicator? (I'm asking innocently; I think it's worth mentioning the reason in the answer.) @hek2mgl: good tip re `pgrep` / `pkill`; they actually come preinstalled on OS X (which is what the OP is on) , but don't support _long_ options there (BSD implementations); `-n` for `--newest`, `-o` for `--oldest` do work, however.

Comment: @mklement0 On a server being up for a long time the PID might not be the right tool to determine which process has been started earlier since once the 16bit PID value has reached it's upper limit lower PIDs will getting reused. I would use something like `ps -oetime`, meaning the execution time which is available (at least on Linux). I'm not sure if `pgrep -n/-o` is doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use awk alone with getline to call out to ps and get the data you want:

`awk -vv_kp="bash" 'BEGIN{ cmd="ps -axu -O T | grep "v_kp" |head -1"; cmd | getline var; close(cmd); split(var,var2," ");print var2[2];}'`

or less awk, more shell:
 
`awk -vv_kp="bash" 'BEGIN{ cmd="ps -axu -O T | grep "v_kp" |head -1|cut -d\" \" -f2"; cmd | getline var; close(cmd); print var;}'`